# View is not updating, rather value of class variable is changed in angular 2 beta

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I'm trying to sort a table column-wise

my html table is following

```
<table class="table tr-table table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th># </th>
                        <th (click)="sortTr('cat')">Category <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i></th>
                        <th (click)="sortTr('vendor')">vendor <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i></th>
                        <th (click)="sortTr('date')">date <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i></th>
                        <th (click)="sortTr('tag')">tag <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i></th>
                        <th (click)="sortTr('amount')">amount <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i></th>
                        <th (click)="sortTr('crd')">crd <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="#inst of trLst | tempConvert:filterTbl.value:2;#i=index" style="border: 1px solid {{inst.color}}">
                        <th scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
                        <td>{{inst.cat}}</td>
                        <td>{{inst.vendor}}</td>
                        <td>{{inst.date}}</td>
                        <td>{{inst.tag}}</td>
                        <td>{{inst.amount}}</td>
                        <td>{{inst.crd}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Console output of variable is in the sorted form but view is not updated
my logic for sorting is follows:

```
sortTr(pr){
        console.log('srt: ',pr);
        let tmpTr=this.trLst;
        this.trLst = tmpTr.sort(function(a,b){
            if (a[pr] < b[pr]) return -1;
            else if (a[pr] > b[pr]) return 1;
            else return 0;
        });
        console.log(this.trLst);
    }
```

demo object value is given below:

```
 this.trLst=[{"vendor":"Yumist","cat":"Personal & Entertainment","bnk":"favicon","crd":"x0939","tag":"#cash","date":"31-07-15","photo_path":"favicon.ico","typ":"img","amount":20642,"color":"#a00","curr":"rupee"},
            {"vendor":"Hauz Khas Social","cat":"Insurence","bnk":"favicon","crd":"x0939","date":"31-07-15","photo_path":"fa fa-user","typ":"ico","amount":19000,"color":"#a0a","curr":"rupee"},
            {"vendor":"Dominos","cat":"Monthly Essencial","bnk":"favicon","crd":"x0939","tag":"#smoke","date":"31-07-15","photo_path":"fa fa-user","typ":"ico","amount":10175,"color":"#aa0","curr":"rupee"},
            {"vendor":"Foodpanda","cat":"Equities & bonds","bnk":"favicon","crd":"x0939","date":"31-07-15","photo_path":"fa fa-user","typ":"ico","amount":9000,"color":"#0a0","curr":"rupee"},
            {"vendor":"Insurence","cat":"Multi Brand","bnk":"favicon","crd":"x0939","tag":"#tax Saving","date":"31-07-15","photo_path":"fa fa-user","typ":"ico","amount":5881,"color":"#00a","curr":"rupee"}];
```

> View is painting for first time.. but when I click on header to sort the coulmn it console the right output but view remains as previous

Logic for pipe is as follows:

```
// We use the @Pipe decorator to register the name of the pipe
@Pipe({
    name: 'tempConvert'
})

// The work of the pipe is handled in the tranform method with our pipe's class
class TempConvertPipe implements PipeTransform {
    strVal:string;
    filterByID:Function;
    filterByAll:Function;
    constructor() {
        this.filterByID=obj=>{
            let rjx=new RegExp(this.strVal+".*",'gi');
            if (obj.vendor.match(rjx)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        };
        this.filterByAll=obj=>{
            let rjx=new RegExp(this.strVal+".*",'gi');
            let keys=Object.keys(obj);
            let isFind = false;
            for(let i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
                if (obj[keys[i]] && (""+obj[keys[i]]).match(rjx)) {
                    isFind = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        return isFind;
        }
    }
    transform(value: any, args: any[]) {
        this.strVal=args[0];
        if (args[1] === 1) {
            return value.filter(this.filterByID);
        }else if (args[1] === 2) {
            return value.filter(this.filterByAll);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

> Means angular 2 is not detecting the change in class variable

Comment: have you added `angular-polyfills.js` to your project `index.html`?

Comment: Yes, I had added it.

Comment: Could you provide the content of the `tempConvert` pipe? Thanks!

Comment: Without the pipe, it works for me. See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/XqHYTqL2BadyVltajVhs?p=preview

Comment: View is working for first time.. but when I click on header to sort the coulmn it console the right output but view remains as previous

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the `sortTr` method is correctly called and the view is refreshed each time.

The problem is in the processing of this function. It sorts the same way each time. This means that you see the difference the first time but not after when clicking again since the order remains the same.

You need to invert the order each time you click on headers to see different (a to z or z to a). Here is a sample implementation for the `cat` column:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.trLst = (...)

    this.asc = {
      cat: true,
      (...)
    };
  }

  sortTr(pr){
    // Invert order
    this.asc[pr] = !this.asc[pr];

    // Sort
    let tmpTr=this.trLst;
    this.trLst = tmpTr.sort((a,b) => {
      var r = 0;
      if (a[pr] < b[pr]) r = -1;
      else if (a[pr] > b[pr]) r = 1;
      else return 0;

      if (!this.asc[pr]) {
        r = -r;
      }
      return r;
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/XqHYTqL2BadyVltajVhs?p=preview

Comment: It's not sorting same way each time, after clicking on header I get console with sorted array as in its parameter but that is not updating to view

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the code is **JavaScript assigns value by reference**

When I make following Changes in above code to kill the reference It worked.

```
let tmpTr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.trLst));
```